# Move qq-upload-list to another part of page in fineuploader?

Tags: jquery, fine-uploader

I'm using the following setup for my fineuploader;

```
$('#jquery-wrapped-fine-uploader').fineUploader({
    request: {
        endpoint: '/Handlers/PhotoUploadHandler'
    },
    multiple: true,
    validation: {
        allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png'],
        sizeLimit: 5242880
    },
    button: $(".buttonUploader"),            
    text: {
        uploadButton: '',
        dropProcessing: '',
        deleteButton: '',
        retryButton: ''
    }
...
```

I'd like to move the qq-upload-list  that gets generated to another part of the page
Is this possible from the declaration of fineUploader like I can for the button, or do I need to dig elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using UI mode, then the [`listElement` option](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options-ui.html) would be your solution.

By default, Fine Uploader will use the `.qq-upload-list` `<ul>` specified in the `template` option, but if you provide your own `listElement` Fine Uploader will use it instead.

```js
$('#jquery-wrapped-fine-uploader').fineUploader({
    listElement: $("#your-custom-list-element"), 
    request: {
        endpoint: '/Handlers/PhotoUploadHandler'
    },
    multiple: true,
    validation: {
        allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png'],
        sizeLimit: 5242880
    },
    button: $(".buttonUploader"),           
    text: {
        uploadButton: '',
        dropProcessing: '',
        deleteButton: '',
        retryButton: ''
    }
```